# Problem with type inference of awaited function return type in TypeScript and PhpStorm

Tags: typescript, phpstorm, webstorm

I have the following piece of code

```
class Foo {
   bar: {
      baz: number
   }
}

class Conflict {
   bar: {
      baz: string
   }
}

function foo() {
   return Promise.resolve(new Foo())
}

async function problem() {
   const auto = await foo()
   const typed: Awaited<ReturnType<typeof foo>> = await foo()
   typed.bar.baz
   auto.bar.baz
}
```

You can see I defined two classes with almost the same structure, important is they have properties with same names. Then a defined a function `foo` that returns Promise that resolved to a `Foo` instance. Then I call it twice with await, once I let the returned type is deduced automatically, once I explicitly set the type to `Awaited<ReturnType<typeof foo>>` which should be exactly what `await foo()` returns.

My problem is PhpStorm treats the two differently.

- If I want to jump to definition of `auto.bar.baz` it takes me correctly to definition of `Foo.bar.baz`.
- But when I want to jump to definition of `typed.bar.baz` it doesn't know where to jump and offers a choice to jump to all known methods of the name `baz`, in this case `Foo.bar.baz` or `Conflict.bar.baz`.

[image: it also shows some different colors]

My PhpStorm is 2022.2.4, no special plugins, just the bundled TSLint (222.4459.28), TypeScript 4.8.3

Is this some problem with the typings? Is the real type somehow different from the explicit one? Or could it just be a PhpStom issue?

This is stripped version of something larger I am trying to build. I've been trying a lot of things and this is the MVE that I could track it down to. I just can't think of any reason why aren't the two treated the same?

Comment: *"My PhpStorm is 2021.3.1"* You're using 1 year old IDE version. if it's an IDE issue it may have been fixed already. I suggest you download and install latest 2022.3 version (was released just a few days ago: https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2022/11/webstorm-2022-3/ ) and see how it goes here. You can have more than one version installed at the same time (IDE-wise settings are stored in separate folders) -- just do not open the same project in both versions at the same time ... and perhaps do your tests in a simple test project first.

Comment: updated to PhpStorm 2022.2.4 (-3 is not available for me yet), also updated all plugins and restarted, issue persists

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem with PhpStorm, it doesn't understand `Awaited<T>`type. Please vote for [WEB-53046](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-53046/TypeScript-4.5-The-Awaited-Type-and-Promise-Improvements) to raise its priority and get notified on any progress with it